# Gracefully stopping greenlets in Windows service

Tags: python, windows-services, pywin32, gevent

Using pywin32 and gevent, I'm creating a Windows service that serves two functions:

1. It runs a web server for a simple web application (using bottle's gevent server adapter, which runs WSGIServer's serve_forever()).
2. It listens for incoming SIP calls (using a gevent-based SIP client) and runs some simple code to respond to calls.

I'd like the service to just keep the web server and SIP client running forever, *but* stop both immediately and gracefully if I try to stop the Windows service. This seems like it should be pretty simple.

What I'm currently doing to run the app is basically to run the web server and SIP client each in a greenlet, and run kill on both greenlets when I want to stop the app (simplified mockup):

```
from bottle import run
from mysipclient import SipClient
import gevent

def sip_listen():
    client = SipClient()
    try:
        client.wait()  # This method blocks on a gevent queue.get call
    finally:
        client.close()  # This does some cleanup, like deregistering from the SIP server, that I really want to run when the service stops!

class App(object):
    def start(self):
        self.stop_event = gevent.event.Event()
        self.server_greenlet = gevent.spawn(run, server='gevent', host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
        self.sip_greenlet = gevent.spawn(sip_listen)

        gevent.joinall([self.server_greenlet, self.sip_greenlet])

    def stop(self):
        self.server_greenlet.kill()
        self.sip_greenlet.kill()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    gevent.spawn_later(10, app.stop)
    app.start()
```

If I run this from the command line, it works great: it starts the app with both greenlets working, then ten seconds later it shuts itself down, running the cleanup code for the SIP client and all.

Now, though, I try to make this into a Windows service, using pywin32's win32serviceutil:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
from app import App

class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'TestService'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'TestService'

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.service_obj = App()

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.service_obj.stop()

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED, (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.service_obj.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

When I install this as a service and run it, I get an exception when trying to kill the greenlets: `LoopExit: This operation would block forever`. Then the service fails to stop, and I have to kill it manually. (I can avoid this by catching the exception, using an event instead of joining the greenlets and setting the event on stop - but this means the cleanup doesn't run at all.)

I'm pretty new to both gevent and working with Windows services, and Google hasn't been terribly helpful. I thought maybe the difference was about how with the command line version I was running stop in another greenlet, so I tried replacing `self.service_obj.stop()` in `SvcStop` with `gevent.spawn(self.service_obj.stop).join()`, but that way it doesn't even throw the exception and just hangs completely until I kill the process.

What's going on here? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? How do I stop the greenlets gracefully on SvcStop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the signal event

```
from gevent import signal

def shutdown():
    print('Shutting down ...')
    server.stop(timeout=60)
    exit(signal.SIGTERM)
gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
gevent.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, shutdown)
gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown) #CTRL C
... start server code
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but could you please elaborate on how I should be using this in this case? In briefly testing with a signal handler that just writes to a log file, it gets run okay when I Ctrl-C in the command line, but doesn't run at all when I stop the Windows service.

Comment: I added one more signal type.  These should catch any time an OS sends a kill command to the process.

Comment: SIGQUIT doesn't exist on Windows.

Comment: SIGTERM should handle these cases.  You may need to add a `gevent.kill` to kill all the threads in your callback.